# como establecer marcas de tiempo en columnas para verificar ultima actualizacion y creacion de un registro - mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo una tabla que es de clientes y tengo agregado dos columnas donde quiero registrar la fecha de la creacion y la ultima fecha de modificacion del registro:

[image: img]

van a disculpar el nombramiento de las columnas, pero esque el ingeniero asi nos instruyo a realizar el nombramiento de tablas y columnas, les dejo los significados de las columnas:

1. **pacecodcli** = codigo_cliente
2. **cacenomcli** = nombre_cliente
3. **caceapecli** = apellido_cliente
4. **cacefecnac** = fecha_nacimiento
5. **caceestciv** = estado_civil
6. **cacenumcel** = numero_celular
7. **cacecorele** = correo_electronico
8. **cacegenero** = genero
9. **cacepaires** = pais_residencia
10. **cacefeccre** = fecha_creacion
11. **cacefecmod** = fecha_modificacion
12. **caceestado** = estado
13. **cacefotper** = foto_perfil

y esta es mi consulta que uso para crear la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE aclient
(
pacecodcli VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
cacenomcli VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
caceapecli VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
cacefecnac DATE NOT NULL,
caceestciv VARCHAR(20),
cacenumcel VARCHAR(20),
cacedirdom VARCHAR(255),
cacecorele VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
cacegenero VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
cacepaires VARCHAR(50),
cacefeccre TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
cacefecmod TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now() ON UPDATE now(),
caceestado TINYINT NOT NULL,
cacefotper TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (pacecodcli)
) 
;
```

mi problema esque al insertar un registro en la columna **cacefecmod**(fecha_modificacion) se agrega la fecha, pero en la columna **cacefeccre**(fecha_creacion) no se agrega nada, esto deberia suceder al reves, en la columna fecha modificacion no deberia agregarse nada y en la columna fecha creacion deberia agregarse la fecha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno al ver el schema de tu tabla se ve que a la columna de fecha de creación por defecto esta quedando con valores `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` en cambio la fecha de modificación esta quedando por defecto la fecha actual del servidor `now()`.

Solo tendrías que cambiar la definición de la tabla

```
cacefeccre TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
cacefecmod TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

Ahora bien en la aplicación, podrías enviar la fecha de creación y cuando actualices le das la fecha de actualización.

Y si. son muy malas los nombre de los campos, 0 descriptivos.

Comment: cacefecmod TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE  now(), ahi recien funciona, sin el ON UPDATE now() nunca se actualizaba la fecha, ahora si.